# Is there a standard way of managing state in a Rails 3.2 Ajaxified application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.2, state

I have an application where I "rolled my own" state apparatus consisting of a big hidden form. I would trap certain click events, make changes to the form, serialize the data, and push it using the jQuery BBQ plugin.

I *never* understood what I was doing. It worked for a short while, but it is so clunky that it has sort of fallen down around me.

The app itself is pretty simple. Think of a flat table with some columns that are laid out in a hierarchical fashion:

```
category
subcategory
product
```

The screen first lists the category, then you drill down to subcategory, etc. My question is, is there a new standard or "Rails Way" to accomplish this state persistence? Of course I want the back button to work as well. My method just seems clunky and unmanageable. And broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO this could be solved graciously with [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/). This is straight forwardly compatible with rails, if you include it through the [backbone-rails](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails) gem.

If you are not quite sure, what you are doing, perhaps you are well of spending some time reading up on how to make a good front-end application with a rails backbone api. There are several screencasts on [railscasts](http://railscasts.com) and some good examples on the [backbone webpage](http://backbonejs.org/).

I hope this helps. Best regards.